# Use ref for Material UI InputLabel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

How can I access the `ref` param of an InputLabel of `@material-ui/core` in TypeScript?

The following code leads to an error with `ref` saying:

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.

```
export class ComboBox extends React.Component<ComboBoxProps, ComboBoxState> {
    private inputLabelRef = React.createRef();

    public render() {
        return <FormControl fullWidth={this.props.fullWidth} variant='outlined'>
            <InputLabel required={this.props.required}
                        id={this.props.id + '-label'}
                        ref={this.inputLabelRef}>
                {this.props.caption}
            </InputLabel>
            <Select labelId={this.props.id + '-label'}
                    id={this.props.id}
                    value={this.props.value}
                    onChange={(e: any) => this.onChangeSelection(e.target.value)}
                    labelWidth={200}>
                {this.renderItems()}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>;
    }

    ...
}
```

I already tried to use generics, trying:

```
private inputLabelRef = React.createRef<InputLabel>();
```

But this leads to the error with `InputLabel` saying:

> 'InputLabel' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.ts(2749)

Follwing versions are in use:

- "@material-ui/core": "4.6.1",
- "@types/react": "16.9.11",
- "@types/react-dom": "16.9.4",
- "react": "16.11.0",
- "react-dom": "16.11.0",
- "typescript": "3.7.4",

Answer (score 0):

The ref in `InputLabel` is forwarded to the root element. So you'll need to type it with the actual html element interface. Changing it to the following should work:

```js
private inputLabelRef = React.createRef<HTMLLabelElement>();
```